# Match Specific File Path Regex

Tags: javascript, php, regex

so far I have this regex `$fileregex = /([a-z]:\\\\([^\\\\^\\.])*)|(\/[^\/.])/i;` but I am very confused on what to do next.

I want to match strings in this format

```
c:\\something\\else\\something
c:\\something\\else\\something.whatever
/etc/whatever/something/here
/etc/here.txt
/
c:\\
```

But I don't want to match, for example

```
c:\oneslash\text.txt
\etc\hi
```

I am really stuck on my regex especially on repeating the optional path, as one could just request the root.Can anyone help me out with the regex?

Comment: What about `^(([a-z]:\\\\)|\/).*$`?

Comment: Did you try any of the answers?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should work:

```
preg_match_all('%[A-Za-z]:\\\\\\\\(.*?\\\\\\\\)*.*|/(.*?/)*.*%m', $input, $regs, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($regs[0]); $i++) {
    # Matched text = $regs[0][$i];
}
```

Result:

[image]

Description of the Regex:

```
                Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
    [A-Za-z]        Match a single character present in the list below
                      A character in the range between “A” and “Z”
                      A character in the range between “a” and “z”
    :               Match the character “:” literally
    \\\\              Match the character “\” literally
    \\\\              Match the character “\” literally
    (               Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
      .               Match any single character that is not a line break character
         *?              Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
      \\\\              Match the character “\” literally
      \\\\              Match the character “\” literally
    )*              Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
    .               Match any single character that is not a line break character
      *               Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
|               Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire match attempt fails if this one fails to match)
   /               Match the character “/” literally
   (               Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2
      .               Match any single character that is not a line break character
         *?              Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
      /               Match the character “/” literally
   )*              Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   .               Match any single character that is not a line break character
      *               Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this:

```
/^([a-zA-Z]\:|\\\\[^\/\\:*?"<>|]+\\[^\/\\:*?"<>|]+)(\\[^\/\\:*?"<>|]+)+(\.[^\/\\:*?"<>|]+)$/
```

This regular expression will match any valid file path. It checks local drives and network path. The file extension is required.

Further references : [The regular expression library](http://www.regxlib.com/)

Comment: I don't want it to match the file extension, however I'll try this and try get rid of the file extension part.

Edit: I don't want it to match one backslash